# Нашел баг в python(другого объяснения я не могу найти). Любую операцию на 0 трактует как деление

Tags: python

```
try:
    a = float(input('first: '))
    b = float(input('second: '))
    c = str(input('action: '))

    dict = {'mod': a % b, 'pow': a ** b, 'div': a // b, '+': a + b,
            '-': a - b, '/': a / b, '*': a * b}

    print(dict[c])

except ZeroDivisionError:

    print('Деление на 0!')
```

[image: []]

Comment: Вообщем любое арифметическое действие с 0 трактует как ошибку - "ZeroDivisionError: float modulo"

Comment: Вы создаёте словарь, в котором вычисляете одновременно все действия, в том числе и деление

Comment: хммм, но все работает если не использовать 0 во втором поле для ввода

Comment: Баг не в Python, а межу стулом и монитором! input завершает строку на "\n", а у Windows управляющий символ завершения строки - "\r\n"... Вот и получается что преобразование идёт от "10\r", "0\r", и операция выглядит как "+\r". Ты уж если открываешь в мелкософте, то хотя-бы trim юзай. А то вообще не ясно что там и как преобразовывать.

Comment: Не веришь мне, проверь на любой Linux машине... Хотя-бы на том-же https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: не совсем понял, дело в том что все считает кроме дейтсвий с нулем, даже если в первом вводе использовать ноль то все работает, а вот во втором все начинаются ошибки, поэтому для меня это кажется чем то странным и нелогичным

Comment: @topsaider Конец строки в нормальных ОС заканчивается 13ым символом он-же "\n" https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336510382/figure/tbl1/AS:813745274105856@1571023400447/Base64-mapping-between-6-bit-values-and-ASCII-characters-value-ASCII-char-value-ASCII.png

В OS семейства Windows конец строки определяется 2мя символами - 10,13 оно-же "\r\n" У тебя каждая строка имеет на борту 1 скрытый символ, который Python не может преобразовать, вот и выходит лажа.

Comment: Вкурил.. И ещё один баг...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать.

Помимо контрольных символов, ты сразу производишь все операции, а это совсем не правильно. Получается что ты сразу считаешь всё... (a % b), (a ** b), ..., (a / b)

10 mod 0   :)))) Ошибка с деления на ноль.

```
try:
    a = float(input('first: ').rstrip())
    b = float(input('second: ').rstrip())
    c = str(input('action: ').rstrip())

    dict = {
        'mod': lambda: a % b,
        'pow': lambda: a ** b,
        'div': lambda: a // b,
        '+': lambda: a + b,
        '-': lambda: a - b,
        '/': lambda: a / b,
        '*': lambda: a * b
    }

    print(dict[c]())

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Деление на 0!')
except ValueError:
    print('Значение должно быть числом')
except KeyError:
    print('Операция неизвестна!')
```

Comment: lambda - это анонимная функция.... Та которая как-бы есть, и которую можно вызвать, но у неё нет конкретного имени https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: да спасибо этот вариант работает. я так понял (в моем коде) из комментариев , что выполняются все действия в словаре (хотя ключ к опредленному из них указан), и если все хорошо то он выдает мне мой определенный ключ, а если в каком возникает ошибка то это все портит даже в правильном ключе?

Comment: Например а=5, b=5... В твоём примере dict = {'mod": 0, "pow": 3125, "div": 0, .... }  В моём примере dict = {функция,  функция, функция, функция,...}  Операция проделывается уже после осознания операции, а не сравнивание все возможных вариантов a и b